# Ubuntu static route two different subnet

Tags: networking, router

I have three Ubuntu virtual machines client, server and router. I want to use these three machines to create a small local network. The configuration is:

```
client: one network interface, 192.168.100.2/24, connected to client-net
router: two network interfaces, 192.168.100.1/24, connected to client-net and 192.168.101.1/24, connected to server-net.
server: one network interface, 192.168.101.2/24, connected to server-net.
client-net will be 192.168.100.0/24, server-net will be 192.168.101.0/24
```

And I have two interfaces on the router machine, eth1(192.168.100.1) and eth2(192.168.101.1)

```
#I try these command in router machine
route add -host 192.168.100.2 gw 192.168.100.1 dev eth1
route add -host 192.168.101.2 gw 192.168.101.1 dev eth2
```

But I cannot ping from 192.168.100.2 to 192.168.101.2.
How could I use route command on the router machine to set up a routeing table from client to server and from server to client? And do I need to do something else on client and server machine? How to connect these three machines into a local network.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS/release details, but you tagged an EOL/ESM release. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL & thus off-topic, Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is supported only by Canonical through Ubuntu Advantage, and only questions specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu are on-topic for EOL or ESM release. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: FYI: the `route` command has been depreciated, and all supported releases of Ubuntu now use `ip route`  - https://ubuntu.com/blog/if-youre-still-using-ifconfig-youre-living-in-the-past